# $x+y = 120^\circ, x\geq 0, y\geq 0.$ max and min of $\sin x + \sin y$

Tags: trigonometry

$x+y = 120^\circ, y = (120^\circ - x)$

$\sin x + \sin (120^\circ - x) = f(x) $

How to find max and min?

Comment: Well, maybe you can use derivatives to find a critical point of f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to differentiate whatever, just use a basic factorisation formula in trigonometry:
$$\sin x+\sin y=2\sin \frac{x+y}2\,\cos\frac{x-y}2=2\sin 60\,\cos\frac{x-y}2=\sqrt 3\,\cos\frac{x-y}2.$$
Now as  $0\le x,y\le 120$, we have $-120\le  x-y\le 120$, so that
$\cos 60\le\cos\frac{x-y}2\le \cos 0$, and eventually
$$\frac{\sqrt 3}2\le \sin x+\sin y\le\sqrt 3.$$

Comment: Good idea.. i didn't think that way.. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use angle sum formula, simplify, recast it into a single trigonometric ratio:

$\sin x + \sin(120^{\circ}-x) = \frac 32 \sin x + \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\cos x = \sqrt 3 \cos(x-60^{\circ})$

Which has an unrestricted maximum value of  $\sqrt 3$ when $x=60^{\circ} + 360^{\circ}m$ and an unrestricted minimum value of $-\sqrt 3$ when $x=240^{\circ} + 360^{\circ}n$ where $m,n$ range over the integers.

With the added constraints, it's clear that the maximum value of $\sqrt 3$ occurs at $x=y=60^{\circ}$ and the minimum value of $\frac{\sqrt 3}2$ occurs symmetrically at $x=0^{\circ},y=120^{\circ}$ and $x=120^{\circ},y=0^{\circ}$.

To understand the restricted minimum, observe that $x$ and $y$ are jointly non-negative for $0^{\circ} \leq x \leq 120^{\circ}$ and that $\cos(x-60^{\circ})$ is increasing and then decreasing for equal intervals on either side of the maximum at the midpoint of that range. So the minimum is reached at the extremes of the range.

Comment: Sorry I didn't show all the steps, I was working mentally and typing on my phone. Post if you need more clarification.

Comment: Thank you.. why the minimum not $x =240^\circ$?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter. Because for $x>120$ degrees, $y$ becomes negative, which is disallowed in your question.

Comment: How to turn this $\sin x + \sin(120^{\circ}-x) = \frac 32 \sin x + \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\cos x = \sqrt 3 \cos(x-60^{\circ})$

Comment: The first part uses the angle sum formulae, reference: https://www.mathwarehouse.com/trigonometry/identities/angle-sum-formula.php and the second part involves the so-called "R" formula, reference: https://www.intmath.com/analytic-trigonometry/6-express-sin-sum-angles.php

Comment: a sin θ + b cos θ = R sin(θ + α). Why you make it cos?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter You can. But you can also use cos. It's explained in the link I provided, just scroll lower down. I chose cosine because the algebra for the max is very slightly easier (it's easier to solve x-60=0 than x+30= 90). You can try it using sine of course.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$\sin(120-x)=\sin(120)\cos(x)-\cos(120)\sin(x)=\frac 12\cos x-\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\sin x$$
May help

Answer (score 0):

[Note that](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) $f(x)=\sqrt{3}\cos(60^\circ-x)\le\sqrt{3}$, with equality at $x=60^\circ$.